# char column in db_schema.xml

Tags: magento2, db-schema

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/configuration/#column-subnode

I didn't find the `char` type (only `varchar`) in the column section but in the length section `char` is present.

I tried to use `char` myself like so:

```xml
<column xsi:type="char" name="hash" nullable="false" length="32" comment="MD5"/>
```

and it seems to properly create a column in the database
[image: char(32) in the table]

**QUESTION**:
Is it supported/recommended in Magento2 to use the `char` type in db_schema.xml and documentation is just not full enough, or it is indeed not supported so there is no mistake in the documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Document is correct**

> **You can get actual data from below file. Please check it.**

```
vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/types/texts/char.xsd
```

> **Here plain text can be persisted without trailing spaces. The length of this field can't be more than 255 characters. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="test_char" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="TEST CHAR DATA TYPE">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="char" name="hash_val" nullable="false" length="255" comment="MD5"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**Example Table Structure:**

[image]

[**CHAR VS VARCHAR**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885630/whats-the-difference-between-varchar-and-char)

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 recommended below format.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="my_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="My Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="my_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity Id"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="my_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <column name="title" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar" comment="Title" length="255"/>
        <column name="description" nullable="true" xsi:type="text" comment="Description"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```